# How to check if a specific user (email/pin) exists in a BlackBerry BES?

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

I have an app that needs to send PUSH notifications to users through a BES.

The problem is that we have multiple unconnected BES servers, and users are sometimes changed from one server to another for load balancing, and we are not notified of that. When that happens I need to find in which server the user is currently on (and then persist that, so next time it will try to push with that server by default)

Is there a way to ask the BES server if a user exists in it? Right now we are attemping to cycle through the servers sending a push notification, and if the user is not registered with it, the connection will throw an exception with a web 403 error, but this is kind of slow.

NOTE: we are NOT using the SDK, we are using plain http post messages to communicate with the server.